# Why JSON.parse ignore some data?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jsonparser

I'm trying to understand why when I'm parsing a JSON response which contains HTML the `JSON.parse` do not fail but ignore such data which I'm trying to fetch from this endpoint `http://registry.npmjs.org/core-js`.

Here an example.

```
fetch('http://registry.npmjs.org/core-js').then(response => 
response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

The property readme is empty, while if you load the endpoint in the browser, readme is completely populated as:

```
   "readme": "# core-js\n\nModular standard library for JavaScript. Includes polyfills for [ECMAScript 5, 2015, 2016, 2017](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript): [promises](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-promise), [symbols](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-symbol), [collections](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-collections), iterators, [typed ... n\n**It's a global version (first 2 examples), for more info see [`core-js` documentation](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v3/README.md).**\n",
```

But after parse it with `JSON.parse` it looks like this

[image]

As you see, readme is empty. Why??

Just FYI, I noticed the original issue using Node.js using

```
body = JSON.parse(body.toString('utf8'));
```

but then I noticed in the browser I have the same result, however, it just happen in some packages when readme has some sort of characters, encoding or whatever that seems to fails silently. eg: with jquery this works fine.

```
 fetch('http://registry.npmjs.org/jquery').then(response => 
 response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Perhaps someone has an idea what's happening here. I've tried many different ways to remove line breaks and so on, but always with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing that there are multiple `readme` properties in this object: the one in the root is empty `""`

But if you open `versions` > `3.0.0-alpha.1` (2 or 3) you will see the `readme` prop is also there and has the value that you provided

```
"readme": "# core-js\n\nModular standard library for JavaScript. Includes polyfills for [ECMAScript 5, 2015, 2016, 2017](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript): [promises](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-promise), [symbols](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-symbol), [collections](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-collections), iterators, [typed ... n\n**It's a global version (first 2 examples), for more info see [`core-js` documentation](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v3/README.md).**\n"
```

Comment: it happens with me all the time :)

Comment: My mistake was assuming that the response was the same as a few weeks ago and something has changed in the npmjs registry, there is a mirror that still returns readme as before in the root of response. `http://registry.npm.taobao.org/core-js`

Answer (score 1):

Agred with david.lucky

There is actually an empty readme

```
"readme":"",
```

And 3 filled "readme"

```
["versions"]["3.0.0-alpha.1"]["readme"]
["versions"]["3.0.0-alpha.2"]["readme"]
["versions"]["3.0.0-alpha.3"]["readme"]
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems something has changed on npmjs registry and I assumed readme should be filled as before.

Comment: No worries mate, happens!